# How to set the grids in bootstrap to work on all screen sizes?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-grid

I have the screen in my app where I use tweeter bootstrap grid layout. While I develop this on large desktop monitor layout looks fine. If i go to mobile device two select drop down input fields will get very small and I can't see any text in them. I originally use `col-xs` on all grids but then I switched to `col-md` and that fixed the problem. So if I open that page on mobile device then each column will be pushed to the next line. However, there is no space between the input fields. Seems like they sit on top of each other. I read few articles about grid layout in bootstrap and they recommend using different column size for each grid element. I'm not sure how that works and if my solution is correct? Here is example of what i have so far:

```html
<script language="javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <form>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-2">
        <select class="form-control" id="frmuser_status" name="frmuser_status" required>
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="2">All</option>
            <option value="1">Active</option>
            <option value="0">InActive</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-2">
        <select class="form-control" id="frmuser_filter" name="frmuser_filter" required>
            <option value="">Filter By</option>
            <option value="1">Name</option>
            <option value="2">Email</option>
            <option value="3">System ID</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="Search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search User" />
          <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-info"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="container">
  <form>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2">
        <select class="form-control" id="frmuser_status" name="frmuser_status" required>
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="2">All</option>
            <option value="1">Active</option>
            <option value="0">InActive</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <select class="form-control" id="frmuser_filter" name="frmuser_filter" required>
            <option value="">Filter By</option>
            <option value="1">Name</option>
            <option value="2">Email</option>
            <option value="3">System ID</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="Search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search User" />
          <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-info"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

In the example above I used the same code with different column size to show the difference on the smaller screen size. What is the best way to decide the column size? Is there any rule how many columns I need for `xm,sm,md` or `lg` columns? If anyone can help or provide any example please let me know. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Please use different css and class for different sizes, this is what i recommend.
I am doing it that way. Use `visible-xs` or `hidden-xs`  classes as described in the documentation [Here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#responsive-utilities).

**UPDATE**

First: Please change all of your columns to col-lg-4  or anything but in lg to be default for large screens.
Second: Use hidden and visible classes where you need to hide something or show something small etc.

**Example**

```
<div class="dropdown hidden-xs">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>


<div class="dropdown hidden-sm vissible-xs">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    Small Screen
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

You have to add custom css according to your need.

Comment: Can you please show example on how to apply `visible-xs` or `hidden-xs` in my example above?

Comment: Basically this solution has identical code with different classes? A lot of redundancy in my opinion.

Comment: yes, using this approach, you will have to use the same code, although its better then nothing, for emergency its good but when you find the correct / better approach use it.

Comment: I'm wondering if this solution has any disadvantages: `<div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-2">Column 1</div>`
`<div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2">Column 2</div>`
`<div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">Column 3</div> `. I have tested and seems to work fine on all screen sizes.

Comment: yes, looks good. and that's the proper way to control it on different screens.